# How to format USB stick, recognized as /dev/sr2

Tags: partitioning, usb

I have an USB3.0 Stick that is recognized as `/dev/sr2`, also as CD-ROM.
How can I remove write-protect and format it?

I already tried a lot of solutions, but those solutions were only for normal USB-Stick. My stick is connected as CD-ROM `/dev/sr2`.

output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 915,5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0 931,5G  0 part /media/mui/yocto
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part
└─sdb5   8:21   0 931,5G  0 part /media/mui/backup
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
sr2     11:2    1  29,5G  0 rom  /media/mui/tmp
```

Comment: Where did this USB come from? This could be intentional as a form of DRM. If so... you need tools from the manufacturer to remove this.

Comment: It came as a present and full of useless information.

Comment: I think it is write-protected in the hardware. I only found Windows tools to resolve it... :(   http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-remove-write-protection-from-usb-drives-memory-cards-3633096/